# In Jira, Is there a gadget that can display a list of reporters/users

Tags: jira

I need a gadget that can display a list of users that have entered a certain type of issue/ticket (in a particular project).

I currently am using the "Issue Statistics" gadget and then setting the statistic type to "reporter".

This works, but also gives me a second column with the number of issues that user has entered.  I really don't want this 2nd column for multiple reasons and wondered if there was either a way of removing it or using a different gadget to just show a list of users that have entered a certain type of ticket.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

There is no any gadget about getting reporters/users list.

Here, all Atlassian gadgets: 
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/GADGETS/All+Atlassian+Gadgets#AllAtlassianGadgets-DisplayingJIRADatainaGadget